# How to get accurate result form google map API v3 or suggestions for address?

Tags: php, geolocation

I am using v2 API of Google maps and we are giving a suggested address depending on accuracy I am getting on the geocode request. But in v3 the response is totally different from v2 API. Any idea on how to get suggested locations from v3 API for the user?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : Just you need to pass latitude and longitude, by latitude and longitude you will get good location.

```
function initialize(latitude,longitude) {
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var markers;

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var place;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 21,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                map: map
            });
        for (i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
            markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]),
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
        }
```

If you stack then reply me.